# django- host a website without python app on cpanel?

Tags: django, hosting, cpanel

I am going to host a website build on the Django framework. There are tutorials on youtube on how to host but they all are using the python app already on Cpanel. But my hosting provider Hostgator does not give the python app in Cpanel. is there any other way to host the Django website without the python app on Cpanel?

Comment: i dont reccommend using cpanel to host a python app in general, since they have many limitations and you're at the mercy of said hosting company of what features they want to enable.

Answer (score 1):

you can host django on digital ocean, with ssh command in the terminal, where you can configure your server with nginx and gunicorn.

tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04-pt

follow the taps.